# Tracking moving Objects using classes

Tags: arrays, class, oop, object

This is a Theoretical question about the use of classes, something which I haven't yet had too much experience. I just want some opinions about whether this would be the best way to go about programming for my task.

The goal of my project is to track objects that move across the frame of the camera, I have been able to detect the objects and store their centre point for each frame (note that this point is only stored until the next frame is read and new points are stored).

I am thinking of using a class store the previous positions of the objects as well as an ID of some kind so that I can differentiate the objects from each other.

Would this be over complicating things? or would it be better to simply store the history points into a basic array of points?

For some more insight, I will be tracking people from an overhead counter, so realistically there shouldn't be more than 15 objects present in the frame at one time. The images below show the detected heads and their centre points (these are the objects being tracked).
[image]
[image]

Comment: @AmiTavory I added some more information, Hope it helps

Comment: Highly depends on what exactly you are going to do with those points (calculations, etc.). Both approaches are valid and have their pros and cons (e.g.: If you are performing lots of mathematical operations on all points the OO approach might have worse performance, however if you always store the previous point(s) for each object the OO approach is probably more readable)

Comment: @JamesMallett No question tagged with [tag:c++] without comprehensible c++ code demos please.

Comment: Basically while the objects are still visible, I want to store where they have moved, and then once they leave the frame I will determine if they have walked from top to bottom or bottom to top. (Camera is mounted above a doorway, want to count people going in and out). So there isn't any more calculations to be done, just analysing the movement history

Comment: @JamesMallett that sounds like it would be a good fit for OOP. For each person you'd create an object which stores all their points (e.g.: using a `vector`) that you can then access once they leave the frame.